# Conditional Flow - Spring Cloud Dataflow

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

In Spring Cloud Dataflow (Stream) what's the right generic way to implement the conditional flow based on a processor output

For example, in below case to have the execution flow through different path based on the product price spit by a transformer.

[Example Process Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpAMe.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`router-sink`](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/router) to dynamically decide where to send the data based on the upstream event-data.

There is a simple SpEL as well as comprehensive support via a Groovy script as options, which can help with decision making and conditions. See [README](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/router/blob/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-router/README.adoc).

If you foresee more complex conditions and process workflows, alternatively, you could build a custom processor that can do the dynamic routing to various downstream named-channel destinations. This approach can also help with unit/IT testing the business-logic standalone.

Comment: Thank you, Sabby.